# Petición GET me cambia los espacios por %20

Tags: angular, api, http, servicio

Estoy ocupando angular, dentro de mi component.ts realizo una petición GET donde paso un parametro con un espacio, ejemplo del parametro seria Saca Puntas, entonces en la url de la peticion deberia quedar así:

http://www.servicio.com/items?params=Saca Puntas

Pero cuando realizo la peticion, la url cambia y queda:

http://www.servicio.com/items?params=Saca%20Puntas

Esto hace que la petición no entregue las respuestas que necesito ya que el servicio estaria recibiendo el string Saca%20Puntas y en la base de datos ese item no existe, espero me puedan ayudar a resolver esto.

Comment: Los espacios para url se codifican ahora para recuperar solo haz un reemplazo ejemplo en C#  param = param.Replace(" ", "%20");

Comment: Hola, como comenta @MiguelZarate, debes realizar la conversión de tu cadena en el lado del backend, no hay manera que pases por URL un espacio. Si aclaras cómo trabajas del lado servidor (lenguaje, framework, etc.) te podríamos ayudar un poco más. Saludos